# Remove window title / window decorations in Gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome

Is it possible to hide window decorations or at least the title bar in Gnome 3.10? I found an extension called "Maximus", but when I try to install it (and Gnome asks whether I want to download it and install), nothing happens.

Comment: That is because Maximus isn't compatible with Gnome 3.10. I even tried to clone the repo and install it, but it doesn't work. So I guess we'll have to wait for the dev to fix it for Gnome 3.10...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that's not possible with Gnome 3. The extension Maximus doesn't work with latest versions of Gnome either. The only way is switching DE for another with offers you that alternative.

Comment: In case you are planning to switch DE, cinnamon has an extension which is a port of maximus. I have used it, and the extension seems to work well with cinnamon 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome 3 and you want to modify all this aspects, check https://extensions.gnome.org/. It's the official Gnome web page for extensions. Just click "On/Off" to activate one and the Gnome desktop recognizes it and automatically installs and active it. (If you want to activate/deactivate them before and check the extensions config, open the *Gnome Tweak Tool* and check the *Extensions* tab)

But if you are looking for *Maximus* or similar extension, there aren't extensions like compatible with 3.8 and 3.10. Just edit the theme like described at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html. Remember search for `frame_geometry name="max"` exactly and add/modify this values.

**Warning:** On 3.10 there's a value with a comment that says it's better put 1 instead 0. Put 1. (If you put 0 there's no problem too, but comments are for something.)

Comment: there is this extension will seems to work with 3.8+ ... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/